# Role playing game for self actualization

Tags: rpg-theory

Is there any RPG that can help in the process of self-actualization?

self-actualization:
the realization or fulfillment of one's talents and potentialities especially considered as a drive or need present in everyone.

So a player can construct their ideal persona, and have adventures in the real world?

Cheers

Comment: To the people who voted to put on hold, any insight abiut where this could be searched for or asked for.

Comment: The /r/RPG subreddit would be a more appropriate forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, almost any RPG can do this, but it's a long-term task.

Trying to fix one's personality defects in a few weeks or months, when playing a few hours a week, is futile. But observing other players, specifically the relationship between their personalities and those of their characters, can be quite educational. If someone is then willing to look at themselves in that light, create characters that differ from themselves, play them, and *keep on* playing them, then they can make useful changes in themselves.

This is the work of years of play, not weeks, and requires playing lots of characters in many different settings. It isn't an easy way to grow up at all, but it works for some people.